# Cannot close Paramiko connection

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to execute some command on remote server using Paramiko and re-purposed some code from net. From Paramiko documents, it say that you have to close the connection. But I am getting errors while doing that.

```py
class ssh:

    paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename_new.log")

    client = None
    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        self.client=paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(hostname=address, username=username, password=password)

    def sendCommand(self, command):
        if(self.client):
            couldNotConnect = False
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command, get_pty=True)
            stdout = stdout.readlines()
            self.client.close()
        else:
            stdout = "Could Not Connect" 
            couldNotConnect = True       

        return stdout


connection = ssh(serverName, userName, passWord)

dfDetails = connection.sendCommand("df -hT")
upTime = connection.sendCommand("uptime")
```

I am getting the below error:

```py
  File "/home/amarc/development/djago/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 508, in exec_command
    chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open_session'
```

But when I remove the `self.client.close()`, it works fine. But I am worried if not closing the connection might cause problem if the program was run multiple times.

And is using `__init__` the right way to create a connection since I might  be supplying the function with different credentials every time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to go for either Fabric (http://www.fabfile.org/) or Ansible and not rely purely on Paramiko since you'll have to reimplement a lot of details. Those tools are already using it but behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

The `SSHClient.close` call has to match with `SSHClient.connect`.

You call `SSHClient.connect` once, but `SSHClient.close` for every command.

Call `SSHClient.close` only once, after you execute all commands.